# overloaded operator% of normal class nested in template class, defined outside classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-classes

I have problem with defining operator% outside my template class. I solved this problem doing it inside, but I would like to know why it doesn't work the other way.

Here is my code:

```
namespace std{
    class vector{};class deque{};class list{};class multiset{};class set{}; class map{}; class multimap{};
};

//---------------------------------------

namespace oop{
    template<typename T> class Array{
        public:
            class value_type{
                public:
                    value_type(T val):_val(val){};
                    T _val;
            };
            Array(int size);
            Array& insert(T ob);
            virtual ~Array(){delete [] _arr;};
            static unsigned int _inserted;
            T& operator[](int i){return _arr[i];};
            Array& operator%(const value_type& right){this->insert(right._val);Array& ref=*this; return ref;};  // inside class it works fine
            unsigned int operator~(){return _inserted;}
        private:
            T* _arr;
            int _size;
    };

    template<typename T> unsigned int Array<T>::_inserted=0;

    template<typename T> Array<T>::Array(int size){
        _size=size;
        _arr=new T[size];
    }

    template<typename T> Array<T>& Array<T>::insert(T ob){
        _arr[Array<T>::_inserted]=ob;
        Array<T>::_inserted++;
        Array<T>& ref=*this;
        return ref;
    }

// But outside it throws an error during compilation: "'oop::Array<T>::value_type' is not a type"
//
//              |
//              v
//
//  template<typename T> Array<T>& operator%(Array<T>& left, Array<T>::value_type & right){
//      left.insert(right._val);                                
//      return left;
//  }
};

//---------------------------------------

#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

//---------------------------------------

int main(){
    typedef oop::Array<char> type; 
    type a(rand()%10+5);
    a.insert('#').insert('C')%type::value_type('P')%type::value_type('P')%'&';
    for(unsigned int i=0; i!=~a; ++i)
        std::cout<<i<<":"<<a[i]<<((i+1)!=~a?" ":"\n");
    return 0;
}
//output: 0:# 1:C 2:P 3:P 4:&
```

Compiler seems to treat type_value like something else than type, why does he?

Comment: It's a dependent name, so not treated as a type name unless you say `typename Array<T>::value_type`.

Comment: That's right now I understand thanks a lot :)